# PL/pgSQL "for loop" + select basic example ("hello world")

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I've been using Postgres for a while, but I'm totally new to PL/pgSQL.

I'm struggling to get a basic *for loop* to work.

This works fine:

```
-- Without SELECT
DO $$
BEGIN 
  FOR counter IN 1..6 BY 2 LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Counter: %', counter;
  END LOOP;
END; $$;
```

But what I really want is to **iterate through the result of a `SELECT` query**.

I keep running into this error:

> Error in query: ERROR: loop variable of loop over rows must be a record or row variable or list of scalar variables

Sounds pretty obscure to me and googling did not help.

There's a table from my own data I want to use (I was hoping to use a `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ‹whatever›`), but I realize I **can't even get the *for loop* to work with simpler data**.

Take this:

```
-- with a SELECT
DO $$
BEGIN 
RAISE NOTICE 'Get ready to be amazed…';
FOR target IN SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,2) LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'hello'
END LOOP;
END; $$
```

This generates the error above too. I'd like to get a simple thing printed to get the hang of the loop syntax, something like:

> hello 1
>   hello 2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, due technical reasons for `FOR IN SELECT` statement, iterator should be declared. It is different from `FOR IN interval` and it is different from PL/SQL `FOR IN SELECT`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The iterator must be declared

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
    target record;
BEGIN 
    RAISE NOTICE 'Get ready to be amazed…';
    FOR target IN SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,2) LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'hello';
    END LOOP;
END; $$;

NOTICE:  Get ready to be amazed…
NOTICE:  hello
NOTICE:  hello
```

Comment: how do I access the content of the series? e.g. to display "hello 1" then "hello 2".

Comment: Make the select this `SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,2) as "counter"`, then  `RAISE NOTICE 'hello %', target.counter;`